# Error con non-object en Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, base-de-datos, blade

Resulta que dos tablas Carro(id,chapa,tipo_carro_id,descripcion) y Tipo de Carro(id,nombre), en donde un carro solo puede ser de un tipo y un tipo puede tener a varios carros. El error me sale en el momento de rellenar una tabla cuando pregunta por el nombre del ripo de carro al cual pertenece el carro debido a que recibe null.  A continuacion les dejo los codigos.

Modelo Carro

```
public function tipocarro(){
  return $this->belongsTo(TipoCarro::class);
}
```

Modelo TipoCarro

```
public function carros(){
  return $this->hasMany(Carro::class)
}
```

El controler de Carro

```
public function index(){
  $carros=Carro::withTrashed()->get();
  $tipo_carros=TipoCarro::all();
  return view(carros.index,compact(['carros','tipo_carros']))
}
```

Y en la vista Index, el foreach que rellena la tabla

```
@foreach($carros as $carro)
  <tr>
    <td>...<td>
    <td>{{$carro->tipocarro->nombre}}</td> //aqui da el error, obtiene el tipocarro nulo
  </tr>
@endforeach
```

Migracion para Carro

```
public function up(){
  Schema::create('carros', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->bigIncrements('id')->unique();
    $table->integer('chapa')->unique();
    $table->text('descripcion');
    $table->timestamps();
    $table->softDeletes(); });
}
```

Migración para TipoCarro

```
public function up(){
  Schema::create('tipo_carros', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->increments('id')->unsigned();
    $table->string('nombre')->unique();
    $table->timestamps();
    $table->softDeletes(); });
}
```

Migracion para agregar la llave foranea a Carro

```
public function up(){
  Schema::table('carros', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->integer('tipo_carro_id')->unsigned();
    $table->foreign('tipo_carro_id')->references('id')->on('tipo_carros')->onDelete('cascade')->onUpdate('cascade'); });
}
```

Comment: Si el tipocarro viene nulo es posible que esta mal echa tu relación, prueba con `$carro->tipocarro` y confirma que si este devolviendo algo

Comment: Estas dos líneas jamás funcionarían en PHP: `$tipo_carros=TipoCarro
  return view(carros.index,compact(['carros','tipo_carros']))`

Comment: Ese fue error mio al escribir el codigo aqui, ya lo arregle

Comment: @Edwin Aquino probe y devuelve nulo

Comment: Entonces esta mal echa tu relación, revisa que las claves primarias esten bien declaradas

Comment: Edwin amigo, No veo error por ningun lado, revise las migraciones y nada, en el gestor de la bd intento insertar el carro y funciona, hasta en el campo tipo_carro_id me carga el combo-box con los valores de esa tabla, revise la vista de la bd en modo diseño y sale como deberia. Algo se me está perdiendo q me está cortando la relacion

Comment: Los carros que tienes guardados en la base de datos, tienen asignado un tipo de carro? Ademas veo que no estas haciendo uso de eager loading. Cambia tu codigo ```$carros=Carro::withTrashed()->get();``` por el siguiente ```$carros=Carro::with('tipocarro')->withTrashed()->get();```

Comment: Agregué eso y sigue devolviendo nulo, arriba puse las migraciones correspondientes

Comment: Cada carro tiene asignado un tipo.

Comment: @AlonsoUreña esta es la consulta que esta ejecutando laravel y que devuelve nulo
```select * from `tipo_carros` where `tipo_carros`.`id` in ('') and `tipo_carros`.`deleted_at` is null
```

Comment: no te dió error en la migración? al poner un string `$table->string('tipo_carro_id')->unsigned();` en la tabla 'carros',  referenciando (`->references('id')->on('tipo_carros')`) a un bigInteger en la tabla 'tipo_carros' `$table->bigIncrements('id')->unsigned();`

Comment: @porloscerros disculpa ese fue error mio a la hora de escribir el codigo aquí

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**SOLUCIONADO**
El problema estaba en que como se conoce laravel usa convenios para nombrar metodos, variables y mas, en este caso era en que en las relaciones laravel usa como llave foranea el nombre de la funcion que establece la relacion mas la la cadena de texto _id, cuando no se define cual es la llave foranea, en mi codigo, en el modelo Carro, el metodo de la relacion se llama tipocarro y la llave foranea establecida en la migracion y definida en el propio modelo se llama tipo_carro_id, y por el convenio estaba buscando tipocarro_id, con razon devolvia nulo, al no existir este en la tabla. El metodo de la relacion quedó de la siguiebte forma

```php
public function tipocarro(){
  return $this->belongsTo(TipoCarro::class,'tipo_carro_id');
}
```

En este caso opté por especificarle el nombre de la llave foránea  como ven arriba, o bien el metodo podria llamarse igual que el nombre dd la llave foránea  sin el _id y sin especificarla en el return.
  *Gracias a los que me ayudaron con sus comentarios*